# Why won't a Netgear Adapter work to Bridge the Connection to my Ethernet port?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

I have a tower with Windows 7 64-bit on it. It connects to the internet through the use of a Netgear WNDA3100 N600 Wireless USB Adapter. I also have an Xbox 360 that I want to connect to the internet through the use of bridging the connection from the Wirelss Adapter to my Ethernet port.

Now, this works fine on both my laptops using internet wireless cards, so I have no idea why it's not working now, when I try to bridge the connection I get this error:

[image]

As you can see in the picture I do have two High-speed internet connections selected.

I tried disconnecting the wireless and then doing it but to no avail. I also tried disabling the wireless connection, but then it disappears from that screen and I have to run Windows Troubleshooting to get it back again.

How can I fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiFi doesn't support bridging without WDS configured on both ends. Unfortunately, WiFi is just enough like Ethernet to confuse people. If it let you make the connection, it wouldn't work anyway. Packets received from the LAN don't have a source hardware address that's paired with the access point. So they can't be bridged to it.

Access points (and your router is acting as an access point) will only talk to their clients, not devices they bridge, unless they are specifically configured otherwise.

Comment: I said in the post WiFi bridging works fine on both my laptops from the same router to the same Xbox. It just doesn't work on my desktop.

Comment: Right, and I explained why it doesn't work on your desktop -- you can't bridge Ethernet to a WiFi client connection. Unless I misunderstood your question, your laptops don't have WiFi client connections, so that's why they work.

Comment: Define: Wifi client connection. I want to accept your answer but I don't understand it fully.

Comment: A WiFi client connection is a normal connection to a typical 802.11 access point with no special configuration on the access point. When a computer typically connects to an access point (using 802.11 a, b, g, or n, it becomes a *client* of that access point. The WiFi specification specifically says that APs shall only send to clients packets destined (at layer 2) for those clients. This means clients cannot bridge. That's why you need WDS to bridge WiFi.

Comment: But then why can both laptops bridge the Wi-Fi in the same manner? Aren't they considered Wi-Fi clients as well?

Comment: You never mentioned that the laptops were bridging. Perhaps your question is missing details. What exactly were the laptops bridging to and what method of bridging were you using? (Perhaps you're confusing ICS with bridging? ICS is not a form of bridging.)

Comment: Look at the picture in the question, the laptops were bridged in the exact same manner. And they were both bridging to the same Xbox. And I did say my laptops were bridging in both the question and the first comment. And using Acronyms without saying what they mean isn't a good practice. To me ICS means Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: @MarkKramer: You have a completely different understanding of your question than I do. But in any event, the answer is very simple -- you can't bridge a WiFi client to an Ethernet segment. This is the problem that WDS connections solve. (If you could, WDS wouldn't be needed. You could just connect to the AP as a regular client and bridge.)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. First, you must go to:

1. Network Connections (The window shown in your post)
2. Right-click on your Wireless Network Connection and go to properties
3. Click on the tab that says "Sharing"
4. Now uncheck the box that says "Allow Internet Sharing"

You should now be able to Bridge the Wireless Network Connection and the Ethernet (Local Area Connection) together.

The reason that you were having trouble is because you can only use one or the other or else it will cause that conflict. Either you use the Network Bridge to share your internet connection through your Ethernet port, or you can share your connection with other computers or any other Wifi enabled device using the "Allow Internet Sharing". Many people use the Shared Wifi Connection as a Wifi Hotspot using software such as "My Wifi Router".

http://www.mywifirouter.me/

Hope this helps anyone who has come to this thread to find answers. The guy who answered first (Not trying to be funny) doesn't know what he's talking about...smh.

Comment: This *might* be spam, but I can't confirm it. Readers: Be on watch for more posts linking to this site.

Comment: This is not spam @DragonLord. I'm answering a question here without intent on spamming people. I suggested MyWifiRouter because it's what I use as a Wifi Hotspot on my PC for my other devices. And since you can connect an Xbox through an Ethernet port or connect using Wifi (except for older models of the 360), I suggested both ways. And I see someone edited my post too. Didn't know they did that on here. I like the numbered instructions better than the "whole" paragraph I wrote though...lol. But still.....didn't know they edit your post.....smh.